# How to sum multiple numbers surrounded by brackets of a single cell with Excel?

Tags: excel, function

Suppose in an excel cell if the text is

Abc(56), Def(1256), Ghi(29854) the result should give summation of all the numbers 56+1256+29854=31166.

This is just an example, there can be n such entries in the cell to total. For ex. abc(56), def(876), ghi(5678), jklm(76584), nopqr(234455) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me in your case, please try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,")","("),"(",REPT(" ",99)),99*{1,3,5},99)))
```

1. replace all ")" -> "("
2. Extract text between "(" and "(" https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-nth-word-from-text-string
3. Get number from word at index {1,3,5} in u's text
4. Convert text to number by 1* then sumproduct all number in array

[image]

Comment: Awesome!!!! Solved one of the biggest problem. Thanks.

However, it is working only for three entries. What if any number of entries needs to be incorporated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 2013+:

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(",")"),")","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.=number(.)]"))
```

- replace the `(`'s with a `)`'s
- create an XML splitting the string on the ')'
- extract only those nodes that are numeric
- SUM the result

[image]

Comment: Never knew about filterxml.. Thanks... Excel 2016..When I pressed just enter it gave me 56.. When I pressed Ctr+Shift+Enter it gave me correct result.

Comment: @NareshBhople  In the newer versions of Excel, you don't need to hit CSE, but in the pre-2016 versions, I think you still do.